# How to remove a hyperlink and add a class in a javascript created unordered list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class, html-lists

I have the following part of javascript:

```
init: function() {
            var html = [];
            $.each(levels, function(nr) {
                html.push('<li><a href="#">');
                html.push(nr+1);
                html.push('</a></li>');
            });
        }
```

It gives the following HTML result:

```
<div>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now I also have a number I get from a HTML5 local storage. Lets say this number is `5`. (`var number = 5`)

Now to what I need. I want al `href` to be deleted and instead a `class` to be added for every `<li>` row that has a number in it that is bigger then `5`. So `if nr > 5 then remove href + add class X`.

In this case the HTML result will look like:

```
<div>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
     <li class="x">6</li>
     <li class="x">7</li>
     <li class="x">8</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But how to do this?

Comment: And which part do you have a problem with? Have you tried something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you modify your `init` function, like this?

```
init: function() {
    var html = [];
    $.each(levels, function(nr) {
        if (nr > number) html.push('<li class="x">', nr + 1, '</li>');
        else html.push('<li><a href="#">', nr + 1, '</a></li>');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2z27U/2)</kbd>

```
$('div > ul').find('li a').filter(function () {
    return +$(this).text() > 5;
}).contents().unwrap().parent().addClass('x');
```

---

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

[.addclass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

[.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

[.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

Comment: This doesn't remove the `a` tags inside the target `li`s

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `each` method:

```
$('a').each(function (i, e) {
    if (e.innerText > number) {
        $(e).parent().addClass('x').html(e.innerText);
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/ZzLXG/2/)